# Laravel: SQL LEFT JOIN with an INSERT (FOREIGN KEYS)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, foreign-keys

I want to populate a new table with the `user_id` from the users table and a random rep_id from the reps table where they have not used a rep, otherwise they want to be assigned the `rep_id` of the rep they have used. I have foreign keys set up for user_id and rep_id, both are nullable but user_id is also the primary key.

I am able to do something like this to select the `user_id` and a `rep_id` in tinker with no problems...

```
$active_rep_array = DB::table('reps')
            ->where('active',1)
            ->pluck('id');

$array_length = count($active_rep_array);

$active_reps = '\'' . implode('\',\'', $active_rep_array->all()) . '\'';

$users = DB::select("
                SELECT users.id AS user_id, 
                COALESCE(rs.rep_id,elt(floor(rand() * $array_length + 1), $active_reps ),0) AS rep_id 
                FROM users 
                LEFT JOIN rep_sessions rs ON users.id=rs.user_id");
```

But I would like to insert this data into a newly created table at the same time. I have this so far (instead of the `$users` query)...

```
DB::insert("
            INSERT INTO user_registration_meta (user_id,rep_id) 
            SELECT users.id AS user_id, 
            COALESCE(rs.rep_id,elt(floor(rand() * $array_length + 1), $active_reps ),0) AS rep_id 
            FROM users 
            LEFT JOIN rep_sessions rs ON users.id=rs.user_id");
```

Which gives me this error in tinker...

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9952085' for key 'PRIMARY'

This is the `user_registration_meta` table...

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| rep_id  | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have truncated in mysql and `ALTER TABLE user_registration_meta AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`

Any ideas why this is coming up with that error?

Comment: So, you only want one row to exist for a user? And you're using the `rep_sessions` table to check if they've used a rep before? If not, you're just adding a random one?

Comment: That's right. A user can have more than one session, but we're just looking for the one rep_id. Ahh, that might be the problem!

Comment: You've lost me, when you say a user can have more than one session does that mean they **can** have more than one row in the `user_registration_meta` table, or are you just referring to the `rep_sessions` table?

Comment: Sorry. You had the right idea in your original comment. There can be more than one row per user in the rep_sessions table, but there can be only one row per user in the user_registration_meta table. I think you've solved the problem. If you want to make that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I've helped but to be honest I'm not exactly sure what the answer is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this and it can be useful to anyone... As @ross-wilson suggested, I was selecting multiple `rep_id` per user in the `SELECT` part of the SQL, which is why I was getting an error. I ended up just having to use `GROUP BY` to make sure that only the last `rep_id` was being used, so each user only gets inserted into the table once.

```
DB::insert("
        INSERT INTO user_registration_meta (user_id,rep_id) 
        SELECT users.id AS user_id, 
        COALESCE(rs.rep_id,elt(floor(rand() * $array_length + 1), $active_reps ),0) AS rep_id 
        FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN rep_sessions rs ON users.id=rs.user_id
        GROUP BY users.id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that error by adding modes, only these modes will be enabled.

```
config/database.php

 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'xyz_db'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'modes' => [
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ]
        ],
```

You can read more about modes here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html